# Treat fold markers as paragraph boundaries?

Tags: folding

I'm trying set up text inside default fold markers to be treated as a distinct paragraph.  To see, in a new buffer:

`:set foldmethod=marker`

```
This is a paragraph 1
{{{
Want text inside this fold treated as a paragraph 2 (as well as the surrounding markers)
}}}
Finally, this would be paragraph 3
```

Currently `vip` on any line will select all lines. Desired outcome for `vip` depending on cursor line:

- line   1: selects text on line 1 only
- line 2-4: selects text of lines 2-4
- line   5: selects text on line 5 only.

One solution is to add empty lines around any folds, but that is specifically what I am trying to avoid in this case.

I have experimented with adjusting `:set paragraphs` but have not found anything yet that has worked.  I also tried `set cpo+={` which helps with `{` motion operator, but not paragraph text object.

Comment: Thoughts: use `.{{`/`.}}` and `:set paragraphs^={{}}`, though I don't how like `vip` behaves in the middle there. Or, mess with `[[` and `][` to jump between braces. Or, well, add newlines :)

Comment: Thanks, this works quite well.  I expected `gqip` on line5 to merge with line 4. but it appears lines with .nroff macros are not touched by `gqip` (despite being visually selected with `vip` ).

Comment: If you have an answer that works for you, please post it!

Comment: Your suggestion is so close.  While `gqip` commands work in all three paragraphs, `vip` command on the bottom line selects the line above it.  I tried putting placing nroff paragraph macro on lines 2 and 2 and 5. This works for both `vip` and `gqip` except `gqip` [does not format a line that starts with an nroff macro](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/36568/how-to-make-gq-tidy-up-a-line-that-starts-with-an-nroff-paragraph-macro).  I also tried `set fo+=w` so that lines without a trailing whitespace count as end of paragraph, but that does not appear to work with `vip` motion operators.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I've been using your clever suggestion to combine the fold marker with the paragraph macro, and it's working great in practice.  If you post as answer, I will mark it answered. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An imperfect solution: use `.{{,.}}` as fold markers and `:set paragraphs^={{}}`. This is imperfect because of the way `vip` behaves with the start and end markers, but `gqip` works as intended.